# How to assign a "keyword" for the values starting with negative number for a column in R?

Tags: r, bash

I had a csv file with 10,000 rows & 2 columns, 1st column with names, 2nd column with log values.
I'd like to add a keyword("red") for the negative log values.
for positive --> "data"
Can some one suggestions please!

```
Example-
names     log      group
571008  -0.2153296   red
571008  -0.2153296   red
00333657 -0.2155359 red
567501  0.2196503    data
321750  0.2200974    data
568683  -0.2221536   red
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A logical index approach:

```
#Data
Data <- structure(list(names = c(571008L, 571008L, 333657L, 567501L, 
321750L, 568683L), log = c(-0.2153296, -0.2153296, -0.2155359, 
0.2196503, 0.2200974, -0.2221536)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

#Create index
index <- Data$log<0
#Assign
Data$Flag<-'data'
Data$Flag[index]<-'red'

   names        log Flag
1 571008 -0.2153296  red
2 571008 -0.2153296  red
3 333657 -0.2155359  red
4 567501  0.2196503 data
5 321750  0.2200974 data
6 568683 -0.2221536  red
```

Comment: HI Duck, nice explanation. Can I know  what is "row.names = c(NA, -6L)" ?

Comment: @park Hi dear, `row.names = c(NA, -6L)` is just the internal index that all dataframes have inside `R`. It is typical to see it when you `dput()` any dataframe. I hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ifelse` to create a new column (instead of appending a string to a numeric class - as it converts the class to `character`)

```
df1$group <- with(df1, ifelse(log < 0, "red", "data"))
df1
#   names        log group
#1 571008 -0.2153296   red
#2 571008 -0.2153296   red
#3 333657 -0.2155359   red
#4 567501  0.2196503  data
#5 321750  0.2200974  data
#6 568683 -0.2221536   red
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(names = c(571008L, 571008L, 333657L, 567501L, 
321750L, 568683L), log = c(-0.2153296, -0.2153296, -0.2155359, 
0.2196503, 0.2200974, -0.2221536)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use logical values to subset and assign.

```
df$group <- c('data', 'red')[(df$log < 0) + 1]
df
#   names        log group
#1 571008 -0.2153296   red
#2 571008 -0.2153296   red
#3 333657 -0.2155359   red
#4 567501  0.2196503  data
#5 321750  0.2200974  data
#6 568683 -0.2221536   red
```